# Bounded variation on the entire real line

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

I know what it means for a function $f$ on a bounded interval $[a,b]$ to be of bounded variation. But what does it mean for $f$ to be of BV on $\mathbb{R}$? Does it mean that $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} V[-N,N] < \infty$? Here $V$ is the total variation of $f$.

On an interval $[a,b]$, $f$ is of bounded variation if $\sup_\Gamma \sum_{i=1}^m |f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})| < \infty$ where the supremum is over partitions $\Gamma=\{x_0 < x_1<...<x_m \}$ of $[a,b]$.

Comment: What definition are you using for being BV on $[a.b]$?

Comment: Added the definition to the question

Comment: Okay. There's an alternative characterisation of BV that says, for $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}$, the total variation of $f$ on $\Omega$ is given by $\|f\|_{BV} := \sup \{ \int_{\Omega} f(x)g'(x) : |g| \le 1 \text{ on } \Omega, g \text{ is smooth}  \}$, and then the BV space on the domain $\Omega$ is the set of $f$ such that $\|f\|_{BV}$ is finite. This definition is good in that it generalises instantly to your case ($\Omega = \mathbb{R}$) and, with a bit of careful consideration, to $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

It means that
$$\sup\sum_{i=1}^n|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|<\infty,$$ where
the supremum is taken over all possible $x_0<\dots<x_n$. And yes it is equivalent to the limit condition you wrote.

Comment: Is there any place that proves this (the equivalence), or follows directly by the definition?

Comment: I don’t understand the question. What I wrote is the definition of a function of bounded variation defined on the real line

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. What I wanted to know is how to prove that your definition is equivalent to $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}V[-N,N]<\infty$.

Comment: If you take a partition for the real line $x_0<\cdots<x_n$ you can find $N$ so large that $[-N,N]$ contains all the points in the partition. So $\sum |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|\le V[-N,N]$. Since $V$ is increasing,  $\sum |f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|\le \lim_NV[-N,N]$. Take the sup over all partitions and you get one inequality. The converse comes from the fact that any partition in $[-N,N]$ is a partition for the real line